# Using multiple dropdowns / drilldowns at once in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, matrix, drilldown, qualtrics

I am putting together a survey for employees in an organization.  The survey asks for the 10 people they work with the most.  I was planning on using a drill down question type and selecting department first and then employee name (since a list of 100+ employees might be cumbersome).  However, the drill down question type only allows one set of drill downs, so qualtrics would only allow the respondents select only 1 employee.  I need to the survey respondents to provide names of 10 employees.  It seems like a matrix-type (horizontal) drop down question is what I want, but it doesn't seem to exist.

As a workaround, I could simply repeat the same drill-down question 10 times, but that takes up so much space and visually seems imposing.  I'm worried about survey respondents dropping out.  I can't imagine I'm the first person to run into this before.  I could do custom javascript, but I haven't seen any similar examples out there.  Any advice?

Comment: Seems to be a SaaS provider.  I'd recommend contacting their support as this doesn't seem to relate to programming and even if they support custom coding, one would want to contact their support first.

Comment: I have contacted their support.  It's not an out of the box feature, but I've found that there are a lot of ways to customize the questions.  Unfortunately, their support doesn't cover anything beyond what's offered in the GUI.